# parameter @gender has no default value

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error when adding parameters to my `OleDbCommand`. The error is telling me that `@Gender` has no default value.

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBER ( [RFID], [ID], [FULLNAME], [POSITION], [GENDER]," & _
      " [DATEENCODED] )VALUES ( @RFID, @ID, @FULLNAME, @POSITION, @GENDER, @DATEENCODED)"


Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@RFID", Form3.txtrfid.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ID", Form3.txtid.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FULLNAME", a))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@POSITION", Form3.txtpost.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@GENDER", Form3.cbogen.SelectedItem))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@DATEENCODED", b))
```

Comment: Did you actually check to see what the value of `Form3.cbogen.SelectedItem` was at the time the code was executed?  If that's what you're assigning to that parameter and you're told that the parameters has no value, that should lead you to suspect that maybe that expression has no value.

Comment: what should i do

Comment: It seems that you are using the default instance of the class Form3. If yes, then probably the cbogen in that instance has no value for the SelectedItem property

Comment: If you need to learn about default instances, start [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

Comment: If you put `MsgBox(Form3.cbogen.SelectedItem)` just before the line `Dim cmd...`, does it show the value you expect?

Comment: Don't yell. All capitals is yelling. :-)

Answer (score 0):

At design time set the DropDownStyle property of the combo box to DropDownList  **Use a data source** instead of add items to the collection at design time or Items.Add or Items.AddRange at run time.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim G() As String = {"Male", "Female", "Other"}
    ComboBox1.DataSource = G
    MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but Microsoft's [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/coding-conventions) recommends "putting the array designator on the type, not on the variable," i.e. `Dim G As String() = {"Male", "Female", "Other"}`. I'm sure I've forgotten which way round many times too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the tip on array designator. As to the question, this should guarantee that the `Form3.cbogen.SelectedItem.ToString` has a value

Comment: It might be best to use "Not known" as the first value to align with [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218), otherwise it will be guaranteeing "Male" if the user does not select a value.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you again. I saw a truly politically correct list on facebook somewhere that was very long and complicated. I had no idea there was a proper way to list gender. I guess my list would still be acceptable if I was coding for Chic Filet. :-)